# How to assign a css class to echo $output

Tags: php, css, output, echo, styling

How can I assign a CSS class to echo $output

I am currently trying this code:

```
    echo '<p class="errormsg">' . $output . '</p>';
```

And my CSS:

```css
.errormsg {
    color: red;
}
```

I dont get parse errors, but the CSS doesnt do anything. Any idea how this might work? Tried several solutions I have found here, but they dont work either.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. So question is: how do you load that css file into your html document?

Comment: your css code should be enclosed within a valid `<style type="text/css>...</style>` element, or within a separate css file referenced in the html page through a `<link type="text/css" src="..." />` element.

Comment: The code is alright...  once try `color:red !important;`...

Comment: @phpfresher No. Just no...

Comment: oh ok... @arkascha..

Comment: @hosnfeuer, any of the answers below are good ones and, because of the brevity of your post and your newness to SO, I made it an opportunity to mention troubleshooting.  Please take the time and effort to choose and accepted answer.  In some cases, an edit with what worked is helpful to future viewers.

Comment: thank you all for your help, it turned out I was dealing with a CSS override

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try writing a page that ONLY has this code:

```
<style>
.errormsg {
   color: red;
}
</style>
<?php    $output='hello'; echo '<p class="errormsg">' . $output . '</p>'; ?>
```

That will work.  You must have something else interfering with your style declaration, or maybe $output has some html that overrides the red color.  **What I'm offering you is more troubleshooting advice than anything**, because your code should work - provided your css is inside a `<style>` tag.

Then, you're just going to have to step-by-step work the working code into your page till you figure out what breaks it.  Troubleshooting...

Answer (score 0):

Works

```
<style>
.errormsg {
color: red;
}
</style>

<?php
    echo '<p class="errormsg">something</p>';
?>
```

Comment: More explanation in answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

put style in head element of your file

```
<head>
    <style>
        .errormsg {
            color: "red";
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

```css
.errormsg {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="errormsg">
  Hello
  </div
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<style>
  .errormsg {
       color: red;
  }
</style>

<?php
    echo "<p class='errormsg'>$output</p>";
?>
```